# Replace all periods with period and newline but avoid "Mr./Mrs." using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am playing around with `sed` trying to better understand it. I have a text file such that there is no newline after each period. As a first task, I wanted to make each sentence start in a new line. To achieve this, I tried using `sed "s|\.|\.\\n|g" <file.txt > newFile.txt`

This worked fine except that it also created a new line after Mr. or Mrs. In order to avoid this, I tried `sed "s|[^Mr]\.|\.\\n|g" <file.txt > newFile.txt`. How can I make it so it skips over creating a new line after `Mr.` & `Mrs.`?

SETUP: Calling `sed` from the command line on file

EDIT:
If I were not to use `sed` (I was using it just to learn more about it), what would be best? Perl as one of the answers has already suggested? Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering who "Mr. sed" is and why you want to avoid him.

Comment: @KeithThompson corrected the title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example to use lookaround regex. You can use a **negative lookbehind** regex:

```
(?<!Mr|Mrs)\.
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jX3jJ5/1)**

[image]

This will match a dot only if it isn't preceded by Mr or Mrs.

The regex explanation is:

```
(?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
  Mr                       'Mr'
 |                        OR
  Mrs                      'Mrs'
)                        end of look-behind
\.                       '.'
```

Btw, you can use **ssed** that supports Perl-mode (-R switch) and would help you to use this lookbehind regex since sed doesn't support lookaround as Bohemian pointed in the comment. On [sed documentation](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html) you can see more about sed and ssed.

You can do:

```
ssed -R "s|(?<!Mr|Mrs)\.|.\n|g" newFile.txt
```

Comment: AFAIK sed doesn't support look arounds

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AFAIK sed doesn't support look arounds, which would make the job easy.

Since the character sequences `Mr.` and `Mrs.` do not appear in any other context than titles, and titles do not appear at line ends, you could solve the problem by doing a subsequent change to remove line feeds after titles:

```
sed 's|\. *|.\n|g' 's|\(Mrs?\.\)\n|\1 |g' myfile.txt
```

Disclaimer: Could be a couple of syntax issues - I don't have a command line handy

Comment: Same problem with this as NeronLeVelu has. Adding an space in front of line like this `This is a test. Here are more data.`

Comment: Running it now I get this message `sed: can't read s|\(Mrs?\.\)\n|\1 |g: No such file or directory`  I tried this: `sed 's|\. *|.\n|g;s|\(Mrs?\.\)\n|\1 |g'` but did not get a good output.

Comment: You have to pass it a file. See edit. Add the `-i` flag to update the file once you're happy with the output

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\. \{0,1\}/.\
/g;s/\(Mrs\{0,1\}\.\)./\1/g;s/.$//' YourFile
```

posix version (so `--posix` for GNU sed) where back reference is not available

Comment: This give a blank space before next line.  Test this line `This is a test. Here are more data.`

Comment: no problem from my aix unless it add a new line at the end (i adapt script for that)

Comment: was it your 'before next line' ?

Comment: Yes, when you have two or more line with `.` in same line. Then next will then start with the space that was after `.`.  Just try to echo data from my comment with the `sed` and you will see.

Comment: ok, i see what you mean. First space after a dot should be removed (but not specified in request). I will adapt the script :-)